# calling a python function that does the drawing in another function

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function that draws a random number between 1 and 3 and calls it in another function in which if the number chosen in the drawing of the first function is 1, it returns a list with up to 3 options among the possible ones in the listOne, if it is 2 returns up to three possible ones from the listTwo and if it is 3 the same thing for the listThree, but the output is not coming out correctly

Thats my code:

```
from random import random, randint, sample, choices
import csv

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = dict()

    def foo1(self):
        return randint(1,3)

    def foo2(self):
        n = 3
        for i in range(n):
            r = self.foo1()
            if (r == 1):
                listOne = ['A', 'B', 'C']
                smpOne = choices(listOne, k = randint(1,3))
                return smpOne
            elif (r == 2):
                listTwo = ['D', 'E', 'F']
                smpTwo = choices(listTwo, k = randint(1,3))
                return smpTwo
            elif (r == 3):
                listThree = ['G', 'H', 'I']
                smpThree = choices(listThree, k = randint(1,3))
                return smpThree
    
    def concat(self, nToGenerate):
        for i in range(nToGenerate):
            self.data[i] = {'foo 1': self.foo1(), 'foo2': self.foo2()}
        return self.data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        nToGenerate = int(input("How tests?"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, not a number")
    test = Test()
    myDict = test.concat(nToGenerate)
    with open('test.csv', "w", newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = list(myDict.values())[0].keys()
        writerFile = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames)
        writerFile.writeheader()
        for key in myDict:
            writerFile.writerow({field: myDict[key].get(field) or key for field in fieldnames})
```

and that is the output for 10 tests:

```
foo 1,foo2
2,['H']
1,"['A', 'B', 'B']"
2,"['A', 'A']"
2,"['F', 'E']"
**1,"['I', 'I']"**
2,['B']
2,"['H', 'G']"
2,['B']
2,"['D', 'F']"
3,"['I', 'G']"
```

As we can see there is an exit that has the number 1 drawn and comes out with a list ['I', 'I']
however, the letter I could only appear on a list whose draw with the number 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `foo1` in:

```
def concat(self, nToGenerate):
        for i in range(nToGenerate):
            self.data[i] = {'foo 1': self.foo1(), 'foo2': self.foo2()}
        ...
```

And then again in:

```
def foo2(self):
        n = 3
        for i in range(n):
            r = self.foo1()
            ...
```

Both invocations to `foo1` return a new pseudo-random number. There is no reason to think that they should always be the same random number.

---

The easiest solution would be to simply have `foo2` take an argument. This argument will be the pseudo-random number, which will be generated in `concat` and then passed to `foo2`. You can eliminate the for-loop in `foo2`, since it does nothing (you return during the first iteration anyway). You can eliminate the if-statements by creating a dictionary, mapping the three possible values of `r` to different lists:

```
def foo2(self, r):
    return choices({
        1: ["A", "B", "C"],
        2: ["D", "E", "F"],
        3: ["G", "H", "I"]
    }[r], k=randint(1, 3))
```

You would also have to change `concat`. For each iteration of the for-loop, we generate a new random number. That random number becomes the value for the `"foo 1"` key-value pair, and gets passed into `foo2` to get the value for the `"foo 2"` key-value pair:

```
def concat(self, nToGenerate):
    for i in range(nToGenerate):
        r = self.foo1()
        self.data[i] = {"foo 1": r, "foo 2": self.foo2(r)}
    return self.data
```

Comment: Aah, now I understand. Thank you, Paul! Is there any way to make this call happen the way I am wishing?

Comment: @JulianaC.F.deMorais I've edited my post. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is arising because you are calling `foo1` twice, once in `foo2` and once when assigning it the `self.data`. These will result in two different results from the random integer function so there is no guarantee that the printed value will match the value passed to `foo2`. You could solve this by returning the `foo1` value in `foo2` along with your return in the form of a tuple and then use indices when assigning to `self.data`. Hope I correctly understood and was helpful.